# Instantiating an object but not storing a reference to it

Tags: c#

In our code we have something like this

```
new MyClass(myProvider);
```

We are not capturing a reference to the class that is created, so I'm wondering what the point is.  Surely when the Initalise method returns it will not be referenced and so GC'd?

Thanks

Comment: maybe they want that myClass do his job but they do not want to do anything with the object afterward?

Comment: @Bestter: Usually you then make this a static function. No point to have a class if you do not plan on using the Class variables. And no way to know it will do it's job, if it could be hit by teh GC the every next line.

Comment: Code inside MyClass's constructor will be executed.

Comment: There is no answer possible until we know what is inside that constructor call.

Comment: @Christopher: you're not wrong. I'm just saying that myClass can do a job, like writing data and you don't want to use that object after that!

Comment: Have you considered side effects?

Comment: It seems the class `MyClass` should be refactored because either the code is useless or the constructor does more things than it should do. Or maybe there is a static constructor that should be executed. But then it belongs into a public static method.

Comment: I just realised after posting what it is. We use a Service Locator pattern(awful) and it self registers - fantastic pattern.

Comment: You may make some configuration of your app for example, where the actual config-instance will be garbage-collected. Anyway I agree it´s probably a code-smell.

Answer (score 0):

Stuff that is not Referenced will be GC'ed evenetually. But you do not know when.

Maybe the Constructor somehow registers it with the Provider, forcing Provider to hold a reference?

Comment: I just realised after posting what it is.  We use a Service Locator pattern(awful) and it self registers - fantastic pattern..

Comment: @Cueball Then I can just echo another poster: This needs to be refactored. Just in case you were not yet certain about that :)